# Code failure insert digits before data of the vector

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am supossed to do a code using function which after asking the user for input,puts number before the vector like this:
if vector is 11,12,13,14
new vector is 1 11 2 12 3 13 4 14 until the vector finishes and then I have to print it but I get an error of vector subscript out of range,aprecciate any help.
Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<double> llena_vector(int x,vector<double> ingreso)
{
cout<<"Ingrese numeros: ";
while(cin>>x);
ingreso.push_back(x);
    return ingreso;

}
vector<double> arma_vector(int contador,vector<double> intercalado)

{
int i=0;
for(contador=1;contador< intercalado.size()+1;contador++);{
    intercalado.insert(intercalado.begin()+i,contador);i++;}
return intercalado;
}

vector<double> imprime_vector(int cuenta,vector<double> imprimir)

{
for(cuenta=0;cuenta<imprimir.size();cuenta++);
cout<<imprimir[cuenta]<<" ";
return imprimir;
}

int main()
{
int y=0;
int q=0;
int w=0;
int f=0;
vector<double> usuario;
vector<double> guardar;
vector<double> resultado;
vector<double> print;
guardar= llena_vector(y,usuario);
resultado=arma_vector(q,guardar);
print=imprime_vector(w,resultado);
system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cleaner version of the code, in working condition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void fill_vector(vector<double>& v)
{
  cout << "Enter 5 numbers." << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    double d;
    cin >> d;
    v.push_back(d);
  }
}

void insert_count(vector<double>& v)
{
  size_t size = v.size();
  for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < size; ++i, j += 2)
  {
    vector<double>::iterator pos = v.begin() + j;
    v.insert(pos, i + 1);
  }
}

void print_vector(vector<double>& v)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    cout << v[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  vector<double> v;
  fill_vector(v);
  insert_count(v);
  print_vector(v);
}
```

Like others (may have) pointed out:

- you didn't need to pass by value (you're basically passing around a bunch of copies), you can pass by reference instead to reduce overhead and speed it up
- you shouldn't put semicolons `(;`) directly behind your loop statements
- `size_t` is often better than `int` when looping on size
- you included `<string>` when it wasn't being used
- you were passing arguments that weren't needed (e.g. a counter)
- you used a while loop for user input, but it's only appropriate when piping in data otherwise it will loop forever; a for loop with a known count is more appropriate for user input
- the function that inserted numbers between the existing elements had an error, you were incorrectly calculating the position to insert
- your code formatting was a mess, making the code very difficult to read
- you shouldn't pollute the namespace (i.e. `using namespace std`), but I left it as is since it's common in example code
- if you're using C++11, I recommend using a for-each loop for printing the vector, and the auto keyword when declaring the iterator

Answer (score 1):

i guess there is a typo: you should remove the last `;` in `for(cuenta=0;cuenta<imprimir.size();cuenta++);`

Edit: as pointed by jrd1, you have this typo in all your for and while loops...

Comment: There were typos but it is standing still in ^Z.Thanks for your help

Comment: @David, do you still have your problem once fixing the typos? First, please also define properly the scope of while and loop with `{` and `}`. Secondly, even if your problem is solved, i would recommend to rewrite the for loop using local scope `size_t` instead of `int`. Third, I would recommend to pass your vector as reference in case of `arma_vector` and const reference in case of `imprime_vector`

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, your code has a number of issues. But, I've modified it to keep it as similar to your original.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

deque<double> llena_deque(int x, deque<double> ingreso)
{
    cout<<"Ingrese numeros: ";
    while(cin>>x)
        ingreso.push_back(x);
    return ingreso;
}

deque<double> arma_deque(int contador, deque<double> intercalado)
{
    int size = intercalado.size()+1;

    for(int i=1; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << i << endl;
        intercalado.push_front(i);
    }
    return intercalado;
}

deque<double> imprime_deque(int cuenta, deque<double> imprimir)
{
    for(cuenta=0;cuenta<imprimir.size();cuenta++)
        cout << imprimir[cuenta] << " ";

    return imprimir;
}

int main()
{
    int y=0;
    int q=0;
    int w=0;
    int f=0;
    deque<double> usuario;
    deque<double> guardar;
    deque<double> resultado;
    deque<double> print;

    guardar= llena_deque(y,usuario);
    resultado=arma_deque(q,guardar);
    print=imprime_deque(w,resultado);

    return 0;
}
```

- All your loops had `;` at the end of them. That's one reason why you're getting your errors, as the semi-colon terminates a statement - hence, your loops were never truly accessing the vectors, which is why you were getting the memory access violations.
- You're passing all your memory by value (which could potentially be slow). Consider using references.
- Your operations suggest that you constantly need to keep pushing new data in front of your vector. If so, then use `deque` (as I did) as it is has functionality designed explicitly for that purpose (insert operations at both ends).

Although, I will say that the logic of your code is quite puzzling at times: i.e. in `arma_vector`, why pass the value of `contador` if you don't even use it? You could have used `i` instead...